# Check in Multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is the function to check in multidimensional array.

```
 public static function inarray($search,$array,$key_=NULL)
{


if(is_array($array))
{

  if(!in_array( $search,$array))
  {
     foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

          Common::inarray($search, $value,$key);
      }   


   }
     else {
        return $key_;
   }
}
else {
     echo FALSE;
}


}
```

This function not returning any value but it is working.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: not returning any value

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function search_in_array($srchvalue, $array)
{
    if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0)
    {
        $foundkey = array_search($srchvalue, $array);
        if ($foundkey === FALSE)
        {
            foreach ($array as $key => $value)
            {
                if (is_array($value) && count($value) > 0)
                {
                    $foundkey = search_in_array($srchvalue, $value);
                    if ($foundkey != FALSE)
                        return $foundkey;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            return $foundkey;
    }
}
```